# bash: Can't get simple 'if' to work

Tags: bash

I don't understand why this simple read doesn't work. Mind you, I am VERY new to bash. :)

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Project Name: " 
read PROJECT_NAME

if [ -n "$PROJECT_NAME" ]; then
    echo "You must provide a project name."
    exit 2
fi

-- snip --
```

When this executes, it asks for the project name. After I press enter, I get "You must provide a project name." and then the scripts exists instead of continuing.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks
Eric

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `[ -z "$PROJECT_NAME" ]`, not `-n`:

From `man test`:

```
   -n STRING
          the length of STRING is nonzero
```

...

```
   -z STRING
          the length of STRING is zero
```

Comment: Yikes. I must have read 'not zero' and not 'non zero'. Thanks! :)

Comment: geocar, stackoverflow doesn't allow you to accept an answer until a certain time after the question was created. The time has now passed and I've accepted it. :)  Again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

to avoid confusion from `-n` or `-z` , you can just use `case/esac` to compare strings

```
case "$PROJECT_NAME" in
"" ) echo "No";;
*) echo "Have";;
esac
```